# Editar temas para prestashop 1.7

Tags: css, prestashop, cms

Estoy intentando generar un tema nuevo para prestashop 1.7 pero me estoy encontrando con una serie de problemas.

1. Copio el tema por defecto y lo configuro como uno nuevo.
2. Edito ficheros para saber cómo trabaja prestashop y no realiza ningún cambio: por ejemplo en el fichero `head.tpl` comento/elimino la línea `<meta name="description" content="{block name='head_seo_description'}{$page.meta.description}{/block}">` y sigue apareciendo en el head.
3. Intento incluir una fuente de Google incluyendo el link justo después de {#HOOK_HEADER nofilter} y tampoco hace nada.

He probado distintos navegadores, vaciando caché y no muestra nada, ni el cambio con el `<meta>` que comentaba antes.

Estoy entrando en el mundo de prestashop y no sé si es que estoy haciendo algo mal o qué me puede estar fallando.

Comment: No conozco bien la 1.7, pero en las anteriores versiones se quedaban las plantillas en la caché y por eso no las mostraba. Mira en Parámetros Avanzados -> rendimiento (o algo parecido que haya en la 1.7) y mira cómo está configurada la recompilación de plantillas

Comment: Justo era eso...al estar probandolo no sabía si es que estaba editando algo mal @CarlosAdrián

Comment: Marca la respuesta abajo como válida entonces, por favor ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira en Parámetros Avanzados -> rendimiento (o algo parecido que haya en la 1.7) y mira cómo está configurada la recompilación de plantillas. Tienes que ponerla para que autocompile el tema y que no utilice la caché.

Nota: recuerda cambiarlo cuando pongas la tienda en producción, por motivos de rendimiento.